# What is a good substitute for avocado oil in Indian food recipes?

Tags: flavor, oil

I am making dal and would like a suggestion for an oil that could be a substitute for avocado oil.

Answer (score 4):

For dal, any oil will work because it is a fairly minor flavor component of the dish. The other flavors (I assume onion, garlic, and spices) will predominate.  I have used vegetable oil, grape seed oil, and olive oil when making dal, all with no problems.

Answer (score 1):

Coconut oil or ghee can be used. Both are commonly-used cooking oils in the Indian subcontinent.

I've lived in Sri Lanka for most of the last 14 years, and those are the only oils I use in my Sri Lankan/Indian cooking. They're also the only oils my Sri Lankan mother in law uses.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly it depends of what kind of Dal you are making. But generally for dal you can use any Oil , Ghee or Butter. But more preferably Sunflower oil. You'll love the taste and aroma of the dal once its done.